# .NET Component for Floor Plan Designer application

Tags: .net, components, designer

My next project is a kitchen designer application (CAD). Something like MS Visio or Home Suite app.

I am looking for a component that I can use as a design editor.

Front view is a must, view from the top and 3D are desired.

I want to be able to:

1. Drag'n'drop components on the floor plan.
2. Select and change size and color of the components.
3. Move components when dimensions of inner components change.

For now it is a desktop application (Windows Forms or WPF).
But would be nice to have an option for silverlight open.

**Question:** any .NET components out there that do what I need (free or commercial)?

Comment: my bad. I am looking for recommendations for components that would act as a floor-plan-editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try NWoods GoDiagram (http://www.nwoods.com/). It is a nice toolkit. I believe it can do floor plans out of the box.